# How should package sequels be represented with tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

For example, [datetime](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) and [datetime2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime2) -- should they really be separate tags?

Comment: Personally I would not be in favor of that.  Most LaTeX users never check the documentation for the version of that package.  We all encourage users, especially beginners, to work with a current updated version of the soffware.  If we have separate tags someone new to TEX.SE probably would miss a subset of the postings.

Comment: @R.Schumacher They are two different packages, incompatible to one another.

Comment: @egreg I had checked TeXdoc.net and datetime2 had no documentation.  I just went to CTAN and I see that it was put there 3/24/15.  After reading both package documentation introductions, they are different packages, with datetime2 being the replacement version for datetime, which will not be maintained in the future.  So, I would now, knowing this, concur with separate tags.   It begs a curiosity question, what is the lag time for documentation to be found by TeXdoc.net

Comment: @R.Schumacher The maintainer must run `tlmgr`, I guess.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: I will poke Stefan, don't worry. `:)`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they should: `datetime` has been declare obsolete and not any more maintained. It is still in the distributions for allowing compilation of older documents without needing to change them.

The new package `datetime2` is different and incompatible with its predecessor, so questions dealing with it should not be confused with those referring to the obsolete version.

Comment: The intent of the question was more of the general case, but I think that the 'incompatible changes' argument applies to most – if not all – sequels. Would you agree?

Answer (score 4):

In general, if the entity they represent is considered *different*, then separate tags would be okay. However, never use version-related tags, as versions become outdated and therefore typically useless.

For example, while we do have a [texlive2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texlive2010) tag, it was has been voted as a synonym for [texlive](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texlive), and rightly so. There would be little value in having a tag for each version of TeX Live. In the same way, version-specific tags for packages (or software) would not be very helpful.

Reference: [What are the guidelines for using version-specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85358/168244)

Comment: If separate tags are OK, but versions should not be used to differentiate them, what should be used to make them unique?

Comment: @PaulGessler: Well in this case, the two packages are named similarly but are different. I would think it best to stick to [tag:datetime] and [tag:datetime2]. You'd probably find similar likeness between [tag:algorithms], [tag:algorithm2e], [tag:algorithmicx]...